# What is more efficient? (web designing)

Tags: php, html, web

Not sure how to word the question but I can give you an example.

Which would be more efficient in terms of like speed and overall "doing it correctly" I guess;

http://www.dlolpics.com/images/troll.jpg

or

images/troll.jpg

I usually leave off my domain URL and do images/troll.jpg but is it really a big difference or if a difference at all?

Any information would be awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously less content in a web page makes it smaller to download, but that is not a good enough reason alone to justify the shorter one.

The main reason to go with a relative URL (the short one), is to make the web site more portable. For example if you rename a directory higher up in the hierarchy or change your domain name you aren't going through the whole site fixing all your URLs.

**Bottom line:** Do it for ease of maintenance, unless you have thousands of links in a page or you are getting web traffic in numbers like twitter it won't make an appreciable performance difference. Honestly it sounds like you are prematurely optimizing the app, and probably focusing on the wrong things unless you already have profiled your site and noticed performance problems related to the size of the HTML.

Comment: Unless you are running a static HTML site, there should be no reason you'd have to fix all your URLs unless you were blind enough to hardcode them. Pretty much everyone uses a function call or a constant to return their base url, and in many cases even that requires no configuration.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference when it comes to speed, other than a few extra bytes being sent, since the former URL is longer than the latter.

I'd go with the latter form `/images/troll.jpg` (remember the first `/`). Otherwise you'll have to modify all your links if one day you decide to move to another domain or you start using HTTPS. A way to overcome this, however, is to use `//www.dlolpics.com/images/troll.jpg`. This will link to whatever protocol you're currently using; HTTP or HTTPS.

The only downside with `/images/troll.jpg` I can think of is if the same site is accessible from multiple URLs, for instance if your site can be accessed both at http://dlolpics.com/ and http://www.dlolpis.com/, in which case a user who visits both sites may download the file twice, first from http://dlolpics.com/images/troll.jpg and later from http://www.dlolpis.com/images/troll.jpg. If the full URL approach was used, the browser would realize that it already had the image cached. This, however, should be solved by only allowing access to one of the above URLs (and redirect the other to it), to avoid link confusion and cookie/caching issues.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some different metrics to consider:

- Download speed: relative URLs are faster because they are shorter.
- URL resolution speed: probably negligible differences that are browser-dependent
- Code maintainability: relative URLs are better; if your site ever changes domains or starts using HTTPS, you won't have to update your links.

Based on these, sticking with relative URLs is a better option.

Answer (score 2):

Its not really a matter of efficiency/speed but more about portability. If your media is on the same server as your webpage, a relative url is preferable to an absolute path because if you move the directory or even the site to another domain, that image location will still always be relative to the page it was requested from.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building a site that will get many, many, many hits, you might want to go with a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) to distribute your media, but if not, either way is about the same in term of speed. Remberber these rules :

```
Rules of Optimization: 
Rule 1: Don’t do it.
Rule 2 (for experts only): Don’t do it yet.
```

Answer (score 1):

No difference at all other than the few bytes saved in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a big difference.

**http://www.dlolpics.com/images/troll.jpg** is an absolute path
while **images/troll.jpg** is a relative path.

Say you change your website domain from **dlolpics.com** to **whatever.com** if you are using absolute paths your images will not load.